# What is the default folder for updating latex packages

Tags: packages

I wanted to download some packages. However, I found it was not pre-installed so I tried to check one of the online repositories. Presently, for new packages, I find it difficult to get online. Also, for pre-installed packages, it is not set to the default directory. Thanks
I use drive C in a windows 10 64-bits system

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use? MikTeX, TeXlive, or something else?

Comment: I use TeXstudio in MiKTeX 2.9